# golang json encoding return {} for an empty map

Tags: json, go

I am trying to get go to actually return me something like this: 
`{"map": {}}` not `{"map":null}` but the encoding/json seems to detect that this is an empty map and only return the latter value.

```
type test struct {
    MyMap map[string]string `json:"map"`
}

func main() {
    testval := test{}
    asjson, err := json.Marshal(testval)
    fmt.Println(testval)
    fmt.Println(string(asjson))
}
```

The output is like this

```
{map[]}
{"map":null}
```

I am looking to get it to be `{"map":{}}` suggestions? I have tried to initialize the map manually, and use a reference for it. Neither seems to yield the output I want. :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`test.MyMap` hasn't been initialized, so it is `nil`. Initializing it will give you the desired result:

```
testval := test{
    MyMap: make(map[string]string),
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/91vZtJeot3

Comment: `map[string]string{}` also can be used